# Not able to compile a package in delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tms

I am working on a project which uses tms components. I have installed it and gave its source path in project options -> search path. But when i am trying to compile and run the program. I am getting the following errors. I tried to remove DBGridPackd2006 in my project and also tried to reinstall tms package but i am getting the same error. Could someone please help! Thanks in advance.

```
[DCC Fehler] E2199 Die Packages 'tmsd2007' und 'DBGridPackd2006' enthalten beide die Unit 'DBAdvGridReg'.
[DCC Fehler] F2220 Package 'tmsd2007' kann nicht compiliert werden.
```

Comment: You should learn how to clean your Delphi environment up. Remove not only this one package but all duplicate TMS units/dcp/dcus/bpls from your system, thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Delphi help:

"The project you are trying to compile is using two packages which both contain the same unit. It is illegal to have two packages which are used in the same project containing the same unit since this would cause an ambiguity for the compiler.

**The only solution to this problem is to redesign your package hierarchy to remove the ambiguity.**"

The way I see it:

1. Packages `DBGridPackd2006` and `tmsd2007` are not meant to coexist together. Perhaps you purchased them separately?
2. You've failed to install them properly. For example, you've tried to install them in wrong order and during compilation you ignored [warning](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/X1033_Unit_'%25s'_implicitly_imported_into_package_'%25s'_%28Delphi%29) about implict importing unit `DBAdvGridReg` to the package which shouldn't have this unit.
3. There is a problem with TMS Pack, in this case you should contact their support directly.